# extract phone number from string (resume) in php

Tags: php, string, extract

need to extract phone number from resume. it can be embedded in a variety of ways, can be in its own line:

```
714-555-1212
```

or in a long line

```
1212 main st fullerton ca 92835  949.555.1212
```

would like to extract it into array - area code, 3 digits, 4 digits

this is what i have so far, but it doesnt work when there are other numbers on same line besides phone number:

```
function get_phone_number ($string){
    $lines = explode("\n",trim($string));
    foreach ($lines as $value){ 
        //echo "Line: ".$value."<BR>";

        preg_match_all('!\d+!', $value, $matches);
        if (strlen($matches[0][0])=='3' && strlen($matches[0][1])=='3' && strlen($matches[0][2])=='4') { 
            $area_code = $matches[0][0];

        }
    }
    return $area_code;
}
```

Comment: And? You want us to write it for you?

Comment: this isn't phpfreaks (of which you will have better chance of code being written for you). At least try first.

Comment: i have this so far, but it doesnt work when there are other numbers on the same line, like street address digits:

Comment: Are you only supporting NANP format numbers?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$areaCodes = array();
$threeDigits = array();
$fourDigits = array();

preg_match_all('/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/',$content,$matches);

if(count($matches[1])>0)
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($matches[1]); $i++)
    {
        array_push($areaCodes,$matches[1][$i]); 
        array_push($threeDigits,$matches[2][$i]);   
        array_push($fourDigits,$matches[3][$i]);    
    }
}

preg_match_all('/\((\d{3})\)-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/',$content,$matches);

if(count($matches[1])>0)
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($matches[1]); $i++)
    {
        array_push($areaCodes,$matches[1][$i]); 
        array_push($threeDigits,$matches[2][$i]);   
        array_push($fourDigits,$matches[3][$i]);    
    }
}
preg_match_all('/(\d{3}).(\d{3}).(\d{4})/',$content,$matches);

if(count($matches[1])>0)
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($matches[1]); $i++)
    {
        array_push($areaCodes,$matches[1][$i]); 
        array_push($threeDigits,$matches[2][$i]);   
        array_push($fourDigits,$matches[3][$i]);    
    }
}

preg_match_all('\((\d{3})\).(\d{3}).(\d{4})/',$content,$matches);

if(count($matches[1])>0)
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($matches[1]); $i++)
    {
        array_push($areaCodes,$matches[1][$i]); 
        array_push($threeDigits,$matches[2][$i]);   
        array_push($fourDigits,$matches[3][$i]);    
    }
}
print_r($areaCodes);
print_r($threeDigits);
print_r($fourDigits);
```

Comment: that works when phone # is separated by dots. but sometimes its (714) 555-1212 or 714-555-1212 or 714 555-1212

Comment: I edited the answer to suit your specification. Edit where necessary and use the or operator. You should be able to figure it out from this blueprint.

Comment: thanks, it works pretty well except for it didn't work on this -  (760) 617-7147 - i am pretty shaky with regular expressions, what needs to be added so that it recognizes the parenthesis around the area code? thanks

Comment: @califmerchant Read up: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/regular-expressions-part1---basic-syntax

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) by clicking the ✔ right next to it.

Comment: Omg free outsourcing in stackoverflow